# Intellij import issue. Spring Boot project not recognized

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, importerror

If I import a complete folder with spring projects in it(microservices). And later I add the spring services which are downloaded from Spring Initializer into the folder.

As you can see in the image you cannot see the blue tag for the other maven projects

If the spring boot project is added after they are installed it will give me the spring boot project as not as spring boot.

Want the blue icon the other projects what is the way for the fix.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaMxL.png)

Comment: I found a solution for this. so, its ok. You need to go to new existing module import the project as maven later drag and drop into the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. So, it's ok. You need to go to new existing module import the project as maven later drag and drop into the folder.
you need to go to:

[image]